# Google Cloud Container - Why so many containers already running in a pod (Instance)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have deployed my first Google Cloud Container Cluster with 1 Pod.
The process was very easy for someone like me.

I am surprised to see that there are already so many containers running in my pod. Are they all needed? Can I kill them to free up the resources?

My image has php-fpm and nginx already.

Does someone know about these docker containers already running in pod and if they can killed?

```
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT       MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
0ed1f7654cba        0.12%               50.35 MiB / 1.662 GiB   2.96%               0 B / 0 B           430 kB / 20.5 kB    8
57a38df9bb86        0.00%               40 KiB / 1.662 GiB      0.00%               0 B / 0 B           0 B / 0 B           1
c073fa866967        0.00%               7.195 MiB / 90.39 MiB   7.96%               0 B / 0 B           2.25 MB / 0 B       5
7f67e38d850f        0.00%               9 MiB / 204 MiB         4.41%               0 B / 0 B           0 B / 0 B           5
10cdfdf5c56a        0.00%               72 KiB / 1.662 GiB      0.00%               0 B / 0 B           28.7 kB / 0 B       1
24e0d2080ae3        0.01%               10.04 MiB / 1.662 GiB   0.59%               0 B / 0 B           0 B / 0 B           5
7674fff85899        0.39%               4.926 MiB / 1.662 GiB   0.29%               0 B / 0 B           0 B / 0 B           7
bd5752cd050d        0.00%               4.348 MiB / 1.662 GiB   0.26%               0 B / 0 B           0 B / 0 B           5
0f2c8dfca968        0.00%               1.906 MiB / 20 MiB      9.53%               0 B / 0 B           0 B / 0 B           4
41df8ceb2050        0.08%               6.145 MiB / 170 MiB     3.61%               0 B / 0 B           463 kB / 0 B        6
5fee54c33b27        0.00%               15.08 MiB / 1.662 GiB   0.89%               0 B / 0 B           5.62 MB / 0 B       6
637395fd17fc        0.00%               17.27 MiB / 300 MiB     5.76%               0 B / 0 B           578 kB / 0 B        5
19604cd9b57e        0.00%               44 KiB / 1.662 GiB      0.00%               0 B / 0 B           0 B / 0 B           1
6eb6c4c08a95        0.00%               40 KiB / 1.662 GiB      0.00%               0 B / 0 B           0 B / 0 B           1
dde35caa0ade        0.00%               36 KiB / 1.662 GiB      0.00%               0 B / 0 B           0 B / 0 B           1
518fe1fa8504        0.00%               36 KiB / 1.662 GiB      0.00%               0 B / 0 B           0 B / 0 B           1
01e703f63e01        0.00%               9.102 MiB / 1.662 GiB   0.53%               0 B / 0 B           3.78 MB / 0 B       4
90570a46da9a        0.00%               36 KiB / 1.662 GiB      0.00%               0 B / 0 B           0 B / 0 B           1
d0bc8aee2208        0.00%               5.691 MiB / 1.662 GiB   0.33%               0 B / 0 B           1.96 MB / 0 B       5
292a08d7bf3f        4.39%               92.9 MiB / 300 MiB      30.97%              0 B / 0 B           1.06 MB / 49.9 MB   35
1ab33b82b9a8        0.00%               36 KiB / 1.662 GiB      0.00%               0 B / 0 B           0 B / 0 B           1
6532f7315806        0.20%               16.75 MiB / 1.662 GiB   0.98%               0 B / 0 B           9.79 MB / 0 B       8
e23e593e7917        0.00%               36 KiB / 1.662 GiB      0.00%               0 B / 0 B           0 B / 0 B           1
```

$ docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                                                                                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
0ed1f7654cba        asia.gcr.io/bidpuuuscorer-100004/bidpuuuscorer@sha256:0ad140000675649bd16c2a9425ab800000afb8fbbe447000000022abffc7a492                        "docker-php-entryp..."   32 minutes ago      Up 32 minutes                           k8s_bidpuuuscorer-cluster-1_cluster-1-1284771230-jphxq_default_dd146037-c6d5-11e7-aa2b-42010a94003d_0
57a38df9bb86        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                                                                                                      "/pause"                 32 minutes ago      Up 32 minutes                           k8s_POD_bidpuuuscorer-cluster-1-1284771230-jphxq_default_dd146037-c6d5-11e7-aa2b-42010a94003d_0
c073fa866967        asia.gcr.io/google_containers/addon-resizer@sha256:0ad140000675649bd16c2a9425ab800000afb8fbbe447000000022abffc7a492                           "/pod_nanny --cpu=..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_heapster-nanny_heapster-v1.4.3-1739311121-0qn57_kube-system_4278ea5b-c6cc-11e7-aa2b-42010a94003d_0
7f67e38d850f        asia.gcr.io/google_containers/heapster-amd64@sha256:0ad140000675649bd16c2a9425ab800000afb8fbbe447000000022abffc7a492                          "/heapster --sourc..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_heapster_heapster-v1.4.3-1739311121-0qn57_kube-system_4278ea5b-c6cc-11e7-aa2b-42010a94003d_0
10cdfdf5c56a        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                                                                                                      "/pause"                 About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_POD_heapster-v1.4.3-1739311121-0qn57_kube-system_4278ea5b-c6cc-11e7-aa2b-42010a94003d_0
24e0d2080ae3        asia.gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-sidecar-amd64@sha256:0ad140000675649bd16c2a9425ab800000afb8fbbe447000000022abffc7a492                   "/sidecar --v=2 --..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_sidecar_kube-dns-488972486-7f055_kube-system_e787de31-c6cb-11e7-a964-42010a94003d_0
7674fff85899        asia.gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-dnsmasq-nanny-amd64@sha256:0ad140000675649bd16c2a9425ab800000afb8fbbe447000000022abffc7a492             "/dnsmasq-nanny -v..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_dnsmasq_kube-dns-488972486-7f055_kube-system_e787de31-c6cb-11e7-a964-42010a94003d_0
bd5752cd050d        gcr.io/google-containers/prometheus-to-sd@sha256:0ad140000675649bd16c2a9425ab800000afb8fbbe447000000022abffc7a492                             "/monitor --compon..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_prometheus-to-sd-exporter_event-exporter-v0.1.7-958884745-6bf2h_kube-system_e7d1613d-c6cb-11e7-a964-42010a94003d_0
0f2c8dfca968        asia.gcr.io/google_containers/defaultbackend@sha256:0ad140000675649bd16c2a9425ab800000afb8fbbe447000000022abffc7a492                          "/server"                About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_default-http-backend_l7-default-backend-2954409777-92mvx_kube-system_e3eeb97f-c6cb-11e7-a964-42010a94003d_0
41df8ceb2050        asia.gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64@sha256:1a3fc069de481ae690188f6f1ba4664b5cc7760af37120f70c86505c79eea61d                  "/kube-dns --domai..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_kubedns_kube-dns-488972486-7f055_kube-system_e787de31-c6cb-11e7-a964-42010a94003d_0
5fee54c33b27        gcr.io/google-containers/event-exporter@sha256:0c86fa393401fe57843be1aa3180cd7fd339ef06fa18234ae5b139a85cfa55ec                               "/event-exporter"        About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_event-exporter_event-exporter-v0.1.7-958884745-6bf2h_kube-system_e7d1613d-c6cb-11e7-a964-42010a94003d_0
637395fd17fc        asia.gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64@sha256:b537ce8988510607e95b8d40ac9824523b1f9029e6f9f90e9fccc663c355cf5d              "/dashboard --inse..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_kubernetes-dashboard_kubernetes-dashboard-1962351010-5p8pc_kube-system_e714c759-c6cb-11e7-a964-42010a94003d_0
19604cd9b57e        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                                                                                                      "/pause"                 About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_POD_kube-dns-488972486-7f055_kube-system_e787de31-c6cb-11e7-a964-42010a94003d_0
6eb6c4c08a95        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                                                                                                      "/pause"                 About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_POD_event-exporter-v0.1.7-958884745-6bf2h_kube-system_e7d1613d-c6cb-11e7-a964-42010a94003d_0
dde35caa0ade        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                                                                                                      "/pause"                 About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_POD_l7-default-backend-2954409777-92mvx_kube-system_e3eeb97f-c6cb-11e7-a964-42010a94003d_0
518fe1fa8504        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                                                                                                      "/pause"                 About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_POD_kubernetes-dashboard-1962351010-5p8pc_kube-system_e714c759-c6cb-11e7-a964-42010a94003d_0
01e703f63e01        asia.gcr.io/google_containers/cluster-proportional-autoscaler-amd64@sha256:003f98d9f411ddfa6ff6d539196355e03ddd69fa4ed38c7ffb8fec6f729afe2d   "/cluster-proporti..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_autoscaler_kube-dns-autoscaler-3880103346-zrpdq_kube-system_014fe72f-c6cc-11e7-aa2b-42010a94003d_0
90570a46da9a        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                                                                                                      "/pause"                 About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_POD_kube-dns-autoscaler-3880103346-zrpdq_kube-system_014fe72f-c6cc-11e7-aa2b-42010a94003d_0
d0bc8aee2208        gcr.io/google-containers/prometheus-to-sd@sha256:c6aaa681e77e55aa7f7017ca55265accde313f8e2e5484ee1d0a4d89ff741c48                             "/monitor --compon..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_prometheus-to-sd-exporter_fluentd-gcp-v2.0.9-bvrj5_kube-system_013d2173-c6cc-11e7-aa2b-42010a94003d_0
292a08d7bf3f        gcr.io/google-containers/fluentd-gcp@sha256:31a2043cc4dc93208c843cc44d1325f7ebf0d18a863bec738fe62b56965dbf62                                  "/bin/sh -c '/run...."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_fluentd-gcp_fluentd-gcp-v2.0.9-bvrj5_kube-system_013d2173-c6cc-11e7-aa2b-42010a94003d_0
1ab33b82b9a8        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                                                                                                      "/pause"                 About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_POD_fluentd-gcp-v2.0.9-bvrj5_kube-system_013d2173-c6cc-11e7-aa2b-42010a94003d_0
6532f7315806        c9b6f1a423cf                                                                                                                                  "/bin/sh -c 'echo ..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-gke-bidpuuuscorer-cluste-default-pool-194fb347-lm7q_kube-system_68d6b70fc1df5b1ba0a7db50c0d7ab91_0
e23e593e7917        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                                                                                                      "/pause"                 About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        k8s_POD_kube-proxy-gke-scorer-cluste-default-pool-194fb347-lm7q_kube-system_68d6b70fc1df5b1ba0a7db50c0d7ab91_0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what some of them are:

- heapster - This monitors CPU and RAM usage on the nodes
- kube-dns / dns-sidecar / dnsmasq - this provides DNS services that allow pods to connect to each other via SERVICE.NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local addresses, making connecting multiple pods easier.
- fluentd & event-exporter - these export logs from your pods to Stackdriver Logging, so you can see logs easily in that interface.
- prometheus - this exports metrics to Stackdriver Monitoring, so you can monitor and alert on metrics.
- kubernetes-dashboard - this provides a web UI you can use to administer kubernetes
- cluster-proportional-autoscaler - this provides a feature allowing the number of pods for a given deployment to scale as needed.
- c9b6f1a423cf - This is providing networking for your pod
- pause - This does nothing. It is used by kubernetes to get some extra control over docker.

All in all, these are normal parts of Kubernetes, and shouldn't be turned off. They generally use very little resources, so don't cause any harm. Kubernetes uses 'namespaces' and keeps these in the `kube-system` namespace. If you use kubernetes tooks like `kubectl get pods` instead of `docker ps` they will not show up usually.

Comment: Thanks for your valued time.